# Show a file input depending on a select value

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

UPDATED FIXED BETTER TO USE document.getElementById :

```
 <script>
    $('.cert_medical').hide();

    $('#activite').change(function () {
        var selected = document.getElementById('activite').value;

        if(selected == 18 ){

            alert("Un certificat Médical est obligatoire pour ce type d'activité");

            $('.cert_medical').show();

        }else if(selected == 19 ) {

            alert("Un certificat Médical est obligatoire pour ce type d'activité");

            $('.cert_medical').show();


        }else if(selected == 20 ){

            alert("Un certificat Médical est obligatoire pour ce type d'activité");

            $('.cert_medical').show();

        }else if(selected == 21 ){

            alert("Un certificat Médical est obligatoire pour ce type d'activité");

            $('.cert_medical').show();

        }else if(selected == 22 ){

            alert("Un certificat Médical est obligatoire pour ce type d'activité");

            $('.cert_medical').show();

        }else if(selected == 24 ) {

            alert("Un certificat Médical est obligatoire pour ce type d'activité");

            $('.cert_medical').show();

        }else if(selected == 25 ) {

            alert("Un certificat Médical est obligatoire pour ce type d'activité");

            $('.cert_medical').show();

        }else if(selected == 50 ){

                alert("Un certificat Médical est obligatoire pour ce type d'activité");

                $('.cert_medical').show();

        }else {

            $('.cert_medical').hide();

        }


        console.log(selected);
    });


</script>
```

I try to display a file input value depending on the result of the select box but the input is didn't display i don't know if i did something wrong ! hope someone could help me .

It's seems javascript not work with the selected == 'Président' (value of the foreach)

here my select :

```
 <select name="activite" id="activite" class="form-control select2">
                            @foreach($activites as $activite)
                                <option value="{{ $activite->id }}">{{ $activite->lb_activite }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
```

here my input file field who is hide by default

```
 <div class="form-group col-md-5 {!! $errors->has('cert_medical') ? 'has-error' : '' !!}">
                        <div id="cert_medical">
                        <label>Certificat Médical : </label>
                        {!! Form::file('cert_medical' , null ,  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Certification Médicale']) !!}
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here my script :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
        $('#cert_medical').hide();

        $('#activite').change(function () {
        var selected = $('#activite option:selected').text();
        $('#cert_medical').toggle(selected == "Président");

        });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of this:

```
$('#cert_medical').toggle(selected == "Président");
```

try to use this:

```
 $('#cert_medical').show();
 $("#cert_medical").val(selected);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply Onix ! i tried but still not displaying me the file field

Comment: working with a form-control  not with form-control select2 ! but now i would like to display it if the value is "Président"